# ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined error occurred while selecting last row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL script to show the last row returned from a resultset.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT
D.DESCRIPTIONID_FK,
D.DAY,
D.TIME,
D.PROFILEID_FK,
E.DESCRIPTIONID,
E.DESCRIPTION,
E.PROFILEID_FK,
E.TONEID_FK,
T.TONEID,
T.TONE_NAME,
T.TONE_FILE
FROM
WA_BT_TBL_DAY D,
WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION E,
WA_BT_TBL_TONE T
WHERE
D.DESCRIPTIONID_FK = E.DESCRIPTIONID AND
E.TONEID_FK = T.TONEID AND
D.DAY = 'Tue' AND
D.TIME <= '11:00'
ORDER BY TIME DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

When I'm querying, it shows me an error:

> ```
> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
> ```

I am using TOAD for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with the `D.PROFILEID_FK` and `E.PROFILEID_FK` as when you try to select all using `*` they will have same name, please try following:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        D.DESCRIPTIONID_FK,
        D.DAY,
        D.TIME,
        D.PROFILEID_FK as D_PROFILEID, -- HERE IS WHAT WRONG
        E.DESCRIPTIONID,
        E.DESCRIPTION,
        E.PROFILEID_FK as E_PROFILEID, --AND HERE
        E.TONEID_FK,
        T.TONEID,
        T.TONE_NAME,
        T.TONE_FILE,
        row_number() over(order by d.time desc) as rn
    FROM
        WA_BT_TBL_DAY D,
        WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION E,
        WA_BT_TBL_TONE T
    WHERE
        D.DESCRIPTIONID_FK = E.DESCRIPTIONID AND
        E.TONEID_FK = T.TONEID AND
        D.DAY = 'Tue' AND
        D.TIME <= '11:00'
) 
WHERE rn= 1
```

Comment: Hi.. just now tried. Still got error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: @HiDayurieDave which column is it highlighting?

Comment: * <-- highlight

Comment: @HiDayurieDave I edited it a bit, can you give it a try?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave glad it helped, it was right under our noses

Comment: Eagle eyes bro!!.. am very sure its not the `order by` but couldn't catch this issue

Comment: @Pரதீப் I couldn't catch it too, only noticed after he said that inner query works well, and it highlights the star`*`

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the following columns

```
.
.
.
D.PROFILEID_FK,
.
.
E.PROFILEID_FK,
.
.
.
```

If you assign a different alias to these columns your problem will be solved.

```
D.PROFILEID_FK d_profileid_fk

E.PROFILEID_FK e_profileid_fk
```

Answer (score 0):

The only column `TIME` was not defined with it's table alias. It should be

```
ORDER BY D.TIME DESC
```

Comment: I tried, but it still show me error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: General question, doesn't `Order by` logically process after `Select` why we need alias name. In Sql Server without that alias it will work.

Comment: @Pரதீப் Your name was so difficult to tag :P.  Yes, we should use after it process select and that make sense. And without alias it work everywhere ;) AFAIK, alias is to shortening the name.

Comment: @HiDayurieDave are you sure ? Because I can't see any other column ambiguous.

Comment: @HiDayurieDave Can you try executing only inner query and see ??

Comment: For inner query it's working without SELECT * FROM() WHERE ROWNUM = 1